# Why numba don't improve the speed of my knapsack function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, jit, numba

I tried to speed up my code with numba, but it's seem to don't work. The program takes the same time with `@jit`, `@njit` or in pure python (about 10 sec). However I used numpy and not list or dict.

Here my code:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit
import random
import line_profiler
import atexit
profile = line_profiler.LineProfiler()
atexit.register(profile.print_stats)

@njit
def knapSack(W, wt, val, n):
    K = np.full((n+1,W+1),0)
    N =  np.full((n+1,W+1,W+1),0)
    M =  np.full((n+1,W+1),0)

    for i in range(n+1):
        for w in range(W+1):
            if i==0 or w==0:
                K[i][w] = 0
            elif wt[i-1] <= w:
                if(val[i-1] + K[i-1][w-wt[i-1]] >  K[i-1][w]):
                    K[i][w] = val[i-1] + K[i-1][w-wt[i-1]]
                    c = N[i-1][w-wt[i-1]]
                    c[i] = i
                    N[i][w] = c
                else:
                    K[i][w] = K[i-1][w]
                    N[i][w] = N[i-1][w]
            else:
                K[i][w] = K[i-1][w]
    N[n][W][0] = K[n][W]
    return N[n][W]

@profile
def main():

    size = 1000
    val = [random.randint(1, size) for i in range(0, size)]
    wt = [random.randint(1, size) for i in range(0, size)]
    W = 1000
    n = len(val)
    a = knapSack(W, wt, val, n)
main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the new function:

```
 @njit
    def knapSack(W, wt, val, n):

        K = np.zeros((n + 1, W + 1),dtype=np.int32)
        # In fact we must only save the previous combinations and the current, 
        # not all :) So N is considerably reduce
        N = np.zeros((2, W + 1, W + 1),dtype=np.int32)

        for i in range(n + 1):
            for w in range(W + 1):
                if i == 0 or w == 0:
                    K[i][w] = 0
                elif wt[i - 1] <= w:
                    if val[i - 1] + K[i - 1][w - wt[i - 1]] > K[i - 1][w]:
                        K[i][w] = val[i - 1] + K[i - 1][w - wt[i - 1]]
                        N[i%2][w] = np.copy(N[(i - 1)%2][w - wt[i - 1]])
                        N[i%2][w][i] = i
                    else:
                        K[i][w] = K[i - 1][w]
                        N[i%2][w] = N[(i - 1)%2][w]
                else:
                    K[i][w] = K[i - 1][w]
        N[(n)%2][W][0] = K[n][W]
        return N[(n)%2][W]
```

*Thank you so much*  MSeifert !!

Answer (score 2):

In fact it's likely impossible to really improve the performance of your current algorithm without changing the approach itself.

Your `N` array contains roughly 1 billion objects (`1001 * 1001 * 1001`). You need to set each element, so you have at least one billion operations. To get a lower bound let's assume that setting one array element takes one nanosecond (in reality it will take more time). 1 billion operations, each taking 1 nanosecond means it takes 1 second to complete. As I said it will likely take a bit longer than 1 nanosecond for each operation, so let's assume it takes 10 nanoseconds (probably a bit high but more realistic than 1 nanosecond) that means we have 10 seconds total for the algorithm.

So the expected run-time with your inputs will be between 1 second and 10 seconds. So if your Python version takes 10 seconds it's probably already at the limit of what can be achieved with your chosen approach and no tool will (significantly) improve that run-time.

---

One thing that could make it a bit faster is using `np.zeros` instead of `np.full`:

```
K = np.zeros((n+1, W+1), dtype=int)
N = np.zeros((n+1, W+1, W+1), dtype=int)
```

and don't create `M` since you're not going to use it.

---

Since you already used line-profiler I decided to take a look and I got this result:

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     3                                           def knapSack(W, wt, val, n):
     4         1      19137.0  19137.0      0.0      K = np.full((n+1,W+1),0)
     5         1   19408592.0 19408592.0     28.1      N = np.full((n+1,W+1,W+1),0)
     6                                           
     7      1002       6412.0      6.4      0.0      for i in range(n+1):
     8   1003002    4186311.0      4.2      6.1          for w in range(W+1):
     9   1002001    4644031.0      4.6      6.7              if i==0 or w==0:
    10      2001      19663.0      9.8      0.0                  K[i][w] = 0
    11   1000000    5474080.0      5.5      7.9              elif wt[i-1] <= w:
    12    498365    9616406.0     19.3     13.9                  if(val[i-1] + K[i-1][w-wt[i-1]] >  K[i-1][w]):
    13     52596     902030.0     17.2      1.3                      K[i][w] = val[i-1] + K[i-1][w-wt[i-1]]
    14     52596     578740.0     11.0      0.8                      c = N[i-1][w-wt[i-1]]
    15     52596     295980.0      5.6      0.4                      c[i] = i
    16     52596    1239792.0     23.6      1.8                      N[i][w] = c
    17                                                           else:
    18    445769    5100917.0     11.4      7.4                      K[i][w] = K[i-1][w]
    19    445769   11677683.0     26.2     16.9                      N[i][w] = N[i-1][w]
    20                                                       else:
    21    501635    5801328.0     11.6      8.4                  K[i][w] = K[i-1][w]
    22         1         16.0     16.0      0.0      N[n][W][0] = K[n][W]
    23         1         14.0     14.0      0.0      return N[n][W]
```

This shows that the bottleneck is `np.full`, `N[i][w] = N[i-1][w]`, and `if(val[i-1] + K[i-1][w-wt[i-1]] >  K[i-1][w])`. Numba isn't going to improve the first two because they already use highly optimized NumPy code, it's more likely that numba will be slower for these. Numba probably can improve the `if(val[i-1] + K[i-1][w-wt[i-1]] >  K[i-1][w])` but that will likely be unnoticeable.

In case the `np.full` is replaced by `np.zeros` the profile changes slightly:

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     3                                           def knapSack(W, wt, val, n):
     4         1        747.0    747.0      0.0      K = np.zeros((n+1, W+1),dtype=int)
     5         1     109592.0 109592.0      0.2      N = np.zeros((n+1, W+1, W+1),dtype=int)
     6                                           
     7      1002       4230.0      4.2      0.0      for i in range(n+1):
     8   1003002    4414071.0      4.4      7.0          for w in range(W+1):
     9   1002001    4836807.0      4.8      7.7              if i==0 or w==0:
    10      2001      22282.0     11.1      0.0                  K[i][w] = 0
    11   1000000    5646859.0      5.6      8.9              elif wt[i-1] <= w:
    12    521222   10389581.0     19.9     16.5                  if(val[i-1] + K[i-1][w-wt[i-1]] >  K[i-1][w]):
    13     47579     784563.0     16.5      1.2                      K[i][w] = val[i-1] + K[i-1][w-wt[i-1]]
    14     47579     509056.0     10.7      0.8                      c = N[i-1][w-wt[i-1]]
    15     47579     362796.0      7.6      0.6                      c[i] = i
    16     47579    1975916.0     41.5      3.1                      N[i][w] = c
    17                                                           else:
    18    473643    5579823.0     11.8      8.8                      K[i][w] = K[i-1][w]
    19    473643   22805846.0     48.1     36.1                      N[i][w] = N[i-1][w]
    20                                                       else:
    21    478778    5664271.0     11.8      9.0                  K[i][w] = K[i-1][w]
    22         1         16.0     16.0      0.0      N[n][W][0] = K[n][W]
    23         1         10.0     10.0      0.0      return N[n][W]
```

But the main bottleneck is still the `N[i][w] = N[i-1][w]` which is probably slower with numba than with pure NumPy. So the improvements you'd get with numba on some of the other parts of the code will likely be unnoticeable (again).

---

For the first profile I used this version of your code (the second profile just changed the `np.full` to `np.zeros`):

```
import numpy as np

def knapSack(W, wt, val, n):
    K = np.full((n+1,W+1),0)
    N = np.full((n+1,W+1,W+1),0)

    for i in range(n+1):
        for w in range(W+1):
            if i==0 or w==0:
                K[i][w] = 0
            elif wt[i-1] <= w:
                if(val[i-1] + K[i-1][w-wt[i-1]] >  K[i-1][w]):
                    K[i][w] = val[i-1] + K[i-1][w-wt[i-1]]
                    c = N[i-1][w-wt[i-1]]
                    c[i] = i
                    N[i][w] = c
                else:
                    K[i][w] = K[i-1][w]
                    N[i][w] = N[i-1][w]
            else:
                K[i][w] = K[i-1][w]
    N[n][W][0] = K[n][W]
    return N[n][W]

import random
size = 1000
val = [random.randint(1, size) for i in range(0, size)]
wt = [random.randint(1, size) for i in range(0, size)]
W = 1000
n = len(val)

%lprun -f knapSack knapSack(W, wt, val, n)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for this reply. I tryied and yes it's better. I found also a very good solution, my N array can be verry much reduce :

Comment: Thank to your modification and mine, now the function is 100 faster than before, and 3-4 faster than pure python

Comment: @blaudantoine You're welcome. Interesting idea with the change of `N`, I haven't thought about that because I assumed that you need the full `N`, since the array was returned by the function. Please don't forget to [upvote the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) if you found it helpful (see [When should I vote up?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)).